# MacBook Pro - Mid 2010 - Memory Errors in AHT

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, error

I have recently inherited a MacBook Pro which occasionally reboots at random. It has 4Gb Ram (2X2). AHT is consistently showing a 4MEM error - e.g. '4MEM/66/40000000:0xa1e45898'

Diagnostics so far:

- Re-seating/cleaning modules - same 4MEM errors.
- Swapping modules between sockets - 4MEM error with different 0x value.
- Testing modules individually - no errors (in either socket).

The above seems to rule out the memory modules or the sockets. Errors only occur when both modules are plugged in. Could this be a timing problem between modules? (Original Apple memory).

I have tried resetting PRAM and SMC - same errors occurring.

Any suggestions as to where to go next most welcome.

Comment: When you swapped the memory modules, the problem moved.  If it was the sockets, the problem would have stayed the same.  Try getting new modules.

Answer (score 1):

Seems it was the memory module(s). Installed two new 2Gb modules and ran AHT extended overnight. No errors.

Comment: That's good news.  Though, the MBP Mid-2010 can take 8GB RAM; I would have put two 4GB modules in there.  If you are within the return period exchange them, this is the route I would take.  You will notice an immediate improvement